# Sequelize for NodeJS and hasMany using UUID error

Tags: node.js, uuid, sequelize.js

I have a model where 'Matches' has many 'MatchRoundTypes'

Matches has a primary key of uuid
matchRoundTypes references Matches with matchesUUID as its column name.

When i try to do a find on Matches that includes MatchRoundTypes i get:

DEBUG: Error: MatchRoundTypes is not associated to Matches!

my query looks like:

```
Matches.findAll({where: ["isPublished = ?", true], include: [MatchRoundTypes]})
```

I have issued the following command prior to all this:

```
Matches.hasMany(MatchRoundTypes, { as: 'roundMaps', foreignKey: 'matchUUID', useJunctionTable: false})
```

I have tried numerous variations on the hasMany statement ... including the foreignKey and not, etc.

Here is my Matches model:

```
sequelize.define('Matches', {
        uuid:    {type: Seq.STRING(36),  allowNull: false, primaryKey: true},
        name:    {type: Seq.STRING(64),  allowNull: false},

    }, {tableName: 'match', freezeTableName: true})
```

Here is my MatchRoundTypes model:

```
sequelize.define('MatchRoundTypes', {
{
        uuid:               {type: Seq.STRING(36),  allowNull: false, primaryKey: true},
        roundTypeUUID:      {type: Seq.STRING(36),  allowNull: false},
        roundName:          {type: Seq.STRING(64),  allowNull: true},
        matchUUID: {
          type: Seq.STRING(36),
          references: "match",
          referencesKey: "uuid",
          allowNull: false
        }

    }, {tableName: 'matchRoundTypes', freezeTableName: true})
```

Any insights are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an alias when defining the hasMany association, therefore you also have to tell sequelize to use that alias when doing eager loading:

```
Matches.findAll({
  where: ["isPublished = ?", true], 
  include: [{ model: MatchRoundTypes, as: 'roundMaps' }]
})
```

Comment: Sorry that is just a cut and paste error ... i was shortening the name of a table for clarity sake of the post and missed that one ... will edit and fix

Comment: on another note ... my table is given another name ... has not mattered yet in my use of sequelize but the obj declaration sets: tableName: 'match',  freezeTableName: true  ... similar for MatchRoundTypes.

Comment: The important thing is `as`. When you define that on the hasMany association, you also have to define it when eager loading.

Comment: On the table name problem: could you show the definition for the table that is giving you problems?

Comment: Not following you on "The important thing is as...." ... perhaps i am not using documentation that has such things but i do not see how you put anything other than the Object name inside the include: array. ... adding the model to post ... really appreciate the assistance!

Comment: ps ... seems that removing the 'as' allows the query to work ... must be something i do not understand about the use of the 'as'

Comment: Yep i found the 'as' in the documentation ... liking sequelize but struggling a bit with the documentation ... guess i should have payed attention in English class.  Cheers.